# How to bound drag and drop element only from 2 sides of another element on Angular 7/8/9?

Tags: angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop

How can I set boundary a drag and drop item using Angular Material only to 2 sides, such as top and left? where the item can be dragged with overflow on the other 2 sides?
I found on the documentation DragConstrainPosition, but I am not sure if that would be fit for purpose or not.
I was also trying to find where the element moving using cdkDragMove and find the element position, but that does not seem to be a good reliable solution.

```
<div class="boundary"> 
    <div id="Draggable" class="Draggable" cdkDrag
    (cdkDragMoved)="dragMoved($event)" 
    [cdkDragFreeDragPosition]="dragPosition"
    cdkDragBoundary=".boundary">
    Drag Me
    </div> 
</div>
```